# using map and for on a nested clojurescript datastructure

Tags: clojurescript

I'm starting a simple project uses Google Spreadsheets for data storage which I access via JSON using [cljs-ajax](https://github.com/JulianBirch/cljs-ajax). cljs-ajax obtains the JSON and converts it to clojurescript datastructures.  I want to pull out the spreadsheet row information which is now part of a nested datastructure, however,  I am having some difficulty in manipulating the data.

Although I can access the rows directly (see below), when I try to put a nested subset into a `let` block, as in : `let [entries (get-in response [:feed :entry])]` , I am unable to use the `entries` local variable using `map` or `for` even though i can call `count` and `first` on it. Is there some limitation to accessing subsets of nested data as its own variable that I don't know about? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
; the request gets data and sends it to the handler function
(defn ajax []
  (ajax/ajax-request
     {:uri query1
      :method :get
      :handler handler
      :format (ajax/json-request-format)
      :response-format (ajax/json-response-format {:keywords? true})}))

; heres the handler
(defn handler [[ok response]]
  (if ok
    (let [entries (get-in response [:feed :entry])]
         ; these will all work showing that entries is seqable
         ; and that I can access the sub-data of an individual entry
         (.log js/console (count entries))
         ; i can call first, second and nth
         (.log js/console (str (first entries)))
         (.log js/console (str (second entries)))
         (.log js/console (str (nth entries 2)))
         ; i can directly access a nested bit of data
         (.log js/console (str (get-in (first entries) [:gsx$suborder :$t])))
         ; map does not work
         (map getentryinfo entries)
         ; for/let does not work
         (for [entry entries]
           (let [soil     (get-in entry [:gsx$suborder :$t])
                 suborder (get-in entry [:gsx$suborder :$t])
                 polygons (get-in entry [:gsx$suborder :$t])]
            (.log js/console soil))))
    (.error js/console (str response))))

; getentry function called by the handler
(defn getentryinfo [entry]
  ""
  (let [soil     (get-in entry [:gsx$soil :$t])
        suborder (get-in entry [:gsx$suborder :$t])
        polygons (get-in entry [:gsx$points :$t])]
        (.log js.console (str soil suborder))))
```

To download and try this code I've [setup a repo](https://github.com/zachcp/soiltypefinder-cljs) which just requires `lein cljsbuild auto` and openeing up `resources/index.html` in a browser

Comment: try doseq instead of for: `(doseq [entry entries] ...`

Comment: thanks @edbond! I guess I missed clojurescript 101.

Comment: in short, `for` and `map` are lazy and you'll need `doseq` or `dorun`. I'll post link if find something more wordy.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311528/clojure-apply-vs-map and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724004/call-to-map-function-doesnt-seem-to-do-anything

Comment: also the yogthos comment about halfway down the page is relevant http://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/comments/2jxb2c/a_hacker_news_implementation_in_clojure_this_is/